# How to set a php session from an app located in a local folder

Tags: php, ajax, session, cordova, session-cookies

I'm developing an app that will be put into phonegap build later, so i'm accessing files from server using ajax and everything works well, the only problem is session won't be set.

my situation is that the url for the site is a normal web address like www.site.com, but the app resides in some folder locally which is like

file:///H:/app/index.html

Is it possible to set a session from this folder?

All other things are set properly like

```
session_start();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Thanks.

Comment: the php will run on the remote server (http://phonegap.com/about/faq/#q_can_you_use_phpaspjsfjavanet_with_phonegap) so why wont sessions work as you expect

Comment: well i don't know about later when i put it into phonegap ,for now i'm testing and it's not working, and the link you provided is not addressing sessions, rather it talks about what i'm already doing, ajax.